# Can a set of linearly dependent vectors form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that a basis of Rn cannot have more than n vectors, because any set of (n+1) or more vectors in Rn is linearly dependent.

However, if I have a set of m vectors, where exactly n vectors are linearly independent, can the set of m form a basis for Rn?

Comment: Elements of a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) must be linearly independent

Comment: You just answered your own question, as you said a basis must have exactly $n$ vectors so if you have $m>n$ vectors with $n$ linearly independent vector, then sure they span $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ but can not be considered a basis unless you get rid of the $m-n$ vectors that are linearly dependent.